# Displaying local notifications when app starts up in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I want to give a notification for an event when the user first enters the app. I have the notifications set up in another viewController handling the calendar that holds the events:

```
 //setup calendar notifications
func createNotification(){
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Event"
    content.subtitle = eventNameArray[0]
    content.body = descriptionsArray[0]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3.0, repeats: false)

    let request =  UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "notification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){
        (error) in
        print(error as Any)

    }
}
```

This notification only triggers in when the user goes to the calendar page.

How do I display this notification when the user boots up the app? Do I need to make changes to the `AppDelegate`?

EDIT: Following a this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx2B8P84tS4) I implemented a new class to push the notifications:

```
import UIKit
```

import UserNotifications

class NotificationPublisher: NSObject {
    func sendNotification(title: String,
                          subtitle: String,
                          body: String,
                          badge: Int?,
                          delayInterval: Int?){

```
    let notificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    notificationContent.title = title
    notificationContent.subtitle = subtitle
    notificationContent.body = body

    var delayTimeTrigger: UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger?

    if let delayInterval = delayInterval {
        delayTimeTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: TimeInterval(delayInterval), repeats: false)
    }

    if let badge = badge {
        var currentBadgeCount = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber
        currentBadgeCount += badge
        notificationContent.badge = NSNumber(integerLiteral: currentBadgeCount)
    }

    notificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self


    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "TestLocalNotification", content: notificationContent, trigger: delayTimeTrigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {
        error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
 }
}

extension NotificationPublisher: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let identifier = response.actionIdentifier

    switch identifier {
    case UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier:
        print("Notification dismissed")
        completionHandler()
    case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
        print("User opened app from notification ")
    default:
        print("Default case was called")
        completionHandler()
    }
 }
}
```

Then inside the viewController of the startup page I did this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{



private let notificationPublisher = NotificationPublisher()
private let calendarEvents = CalendarController()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()     
    print("Events to show in notification: ", calendarEvents.descriptionsArray)

    notificationPublisher.sendNotification(title: "Hey", subtitle: "Testing", body: "Is this working?", badge: 1, delayInterval: nil )

  }
}
```

The app shows the notification on startup but I cannot display anything inside the `calendarEvents.descriptionsArray` as it is empty. How do I make it so the array is filled with data from a server so that the notification can display the event?

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply the same in `AppDelegate` class on method `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
you may want to save a flag to `NSUSerDefaults` to indicate whether it is the very first launch of the app or not and act accordingly (display local notification)

Comment: Does that mean that I set up the all the content inside `AppDelegate`?

Comment: yes, or you can call some kind of helper function / class from there to do the work

Comment: Do use an extension inside the class with the notification to call to `AppDelegate`?